# Is there a intellij template grammar reference?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using `intellij IDEA`, and I want to custom getter template.

The code is like this, looks like some kind of template language

```
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
  #if ($StringUtil.startsWithIgnoreCase($name, 'is'))
    #set($name = $StringUtil.decapitalize($name))
  #else
    is##
#end
#else
  get##
#end
${name}() {
  return $field.name;
}
```

But I can`t find any reference or tutorial, could you give me some info about it?

Answer (score 2):

after a long search, I find it is base on [velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)

Velocity is a Java-based template engine. It permits anyone to use a simple yet powerful template language to reference objects defined in Java code.